# How to insert data in to mysql using union concept in java

Tags: java, mysql

I had created successfully in mysql, but it is not working in java. Can any Suggest  the answer.

Query in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO src_extract(src_data,column_name,table_name) 
SELECT empno, 'empno', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails
UNION SELECT empname, 'empname', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails
UNION SELECT email, 'email', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails 
UNION SELECT country, 'country', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails.
```

But in java how should we execute the same Query.

```
String query = "insert into source_extract(srcdata,column_name,table_name)"
    + "values (SELECT empno, 'empno', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails "
    + " UNION "
    + "SELECT empname, 'empname', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails"
    + "UNION "
    + "SELECT email, 'email', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails"
    + " UNION "
    + "SELECT country, 'country', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails";
PreparedStatement prep = myConn.prepareStatement(query); 
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) prep.executeQuery(); 
mystmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Also, `src_data` in the first version, `srcdata` in the second. And `src_extract` in the first and `source_extract` in the second. Seriously, those are two different queries, how do you expect them to work the same way?

Comment: I have created a new table i.e; source_extract table and trying to insert data in to it by using java like

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: Use `executeUpdate` instead

Comment: And please, next time add this information directly in the question, don't wait for other users to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the values  work but only the select

```
String query = "insert into source_extract(srcdata,column_name,table_name) "
+ " SELECT empno, 'empno', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails "
+ " UNION "
+ " SELECT empname, 'empname', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails"
+ " UNION "
+ " SELECT email, 'email', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails"
+ " UNION "
+ " SELECT country, 'country', 'empdetails' FROM empdetails ";
```